# How to take character input if we have multiple white spaces?

Tags: c, input, character

Hello Everyone,
              I am solving a question     http://www.spoj.com/problems/ARITH2/. In this question I have to take first integer input then a character input, but there is no limitations of white spaces. how do I take only character input then integer input?

Comment: Please present the requirements of your problem explicitly, instead of giving a link to an external site. Please also provide your code that attempts to solve the problem, and describe which error you want to fix in it.

Comment: I want to scan only character if we have multiple white spaces before the character and after the character

Answer (score 1):

Use any whitespace character before `%c`. This character will discard all whitespace characters ,if any, until the first non-whitespace character. For example:

```
scanf(" %c", &character);
```

Note that you do not need this before `%d` as `%d` already discards leading whitespace characters.

As for the link to the challenge provided in the question, you can use

```
scanf("%d", &no_of_test_cases);
```

to get the number of test cases and

```
scanf("%d %c", &number, &character);
```

to get each number and character. Use the above `scanf` in a loop until `character` becomes `'='`. You'll get each line for each test case by doing this.

Comment: I don't think that would make problems. Check the edit. Try it out. Reply if you face any problems.

Comment: if we have 1  +2= like expression c will be white space

Comment: No. Try it out first.